# Difference in behavior of readLines() function in R 3.6 compared to 3.5.x

Tags: r

We've used readLines() to pull the code for a webpage, and then parsed the XML elements to extract pieces of it. Upon upgrade to 3.6, we noticed some scripts weren't working. As it turns out, readLines isn't extracting the whole page in some instances.

On R 3.5.3:

```
> length(readLines("https://masternodes.online"))

[1] 7717
Warning message:
In readLines("https://masternodes.online") :
  incomplete final line found on 'https://masternodes.online'
```

On the same machine, R 3.6.0:

```
> length(readLines("https://masternodes.online"))

[1] 4957
Warning message:
In readLines("https://masternodes.online") :
  incomplete final line found on 'https://masternodes.online'
```

Can anyone explain the reason for the discrepancy? This doesn't appear to be an issue of an IP-specific homepage, or anything like that, as these tests were performed on the same machine.

Diff between the two results: https://www.diffchecker.com/TezbTMeY

Comment: you could try with `XML` or `rvest` packages

Comment: Well, what does the content of the returned strings look like? Show the output you get so we don't have to install both versions of R ourselves to test and verify your request.

Comment: I pasted both here: https://www.diffchecker.com/TezbTMeY

Answer (score 3):

I suspect different user agents may be the cause.

```
readLines("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent") -> z
grep("Your User Agent is", z) -> w
z[seq(w, w+4)]
```

On linux R 3.5.3 this shows `R (3.5.3 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)`.

On R 3.6.0 mac it shows `libcurl/7.54.0`.

Using `httr::get`

```
z <- rawToChar(httr::GET("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent")$content)
```

The user agent is `libcurl/7.54.0 r-curl/3.3 httr/1.4.0`.

And using `httr` on the website:

```
z <- httr::GET("https://masternodes.online")$content
```

returns `4957` lines regardless of R version.

Note you can also change the user agent manually and confirm:

```
ua <- user_agent("R (3.5.3 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)")
z <- rawToChar(httr::GET("https://masternodes.online", ua)$content)
```

Although the parsing is a little different than `readLines`, it looks to be the same.

Comment: Considering the [changelog of R 3.6.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000641.html), this sounds plausible: *"`download.file()` and `url()` get new argument `headers` for custom HTTP headers, e.g., allowing to perform basic http authentication, thanks to a patch contributed by G'abor Cs'ardi."*

Comment: I wonder if the user agent change is enough to be considered a "bug", since it could break pre-existing scripts (as the OP has seemingly found out ;)

Answer (score 1):

As @thc suggested different user agents are the cause of the problem.
From the R 3.6.0 changelog

```
The default ‘user agent’ has been changed when accessing http:// and https:// sites using libcurl. (A site was found which caused libcurl to infinite-loop with the previous default.)
```

Falling back to the earlier used user agent would revert the change in returned data.

```
length(readLines(url("https://masternodes.online",headers=c("User-Agent"=options("HTTPUserAgent")[[1]]))))
```